# How to cookie visitors (PHP) who visit a certain page?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a client who has a landing page that is ranking well in organic search results. The site is built using a LAMP stack, PHP.

For example, they might have a page like www.domain.com/manhattan-accounting

Now, that page is really only accessible via organic results or the sitemap, because it's not part of the main navigation (and probably shouldn't be, because it's text heavy).

They want to cookie any visitor who comes across that page, so that upon the contact page's contact form submission, it CCs to an additional email address.

For example, let's say the contact form at www.domain.com/contact goes to contact@domain.com for regular visitors. For any visitor who has either come in via www.domain.com/manhattan-accounting (the organic landing page) or has navigated to www.domain.com/manhattan-accounting during surfing the site... if that user (who we need to cookie obviously once they hit that /manhattan-accounting/ page) submits the contact form located at www.domain.com/contact
we need to have it go to contact@domain.com and also accounting@domain.com

Thanks in advance for your responses. I am newer to PHP and have been searching previous questions but was unable to find anything like this.

Comment: Is the contact form handler all custom PHP or is it one of those cookie-cutter scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are one way, but I would use a session.

This is a rather simplified process, and not flexible, but will suffice...

On top of the **manhattan-accounting** page,

```
<?php
session_start();  // Ideally, this is done in a bootstrap/include file
$_SESSION['manhattan-accounting'] = TRUE;
```

On top of the **contact page**,

```
<?php
session_start();  // Again, this should go in a bootstrap file.
```

On the **contact page**, where email recipients are determined:

```
<?php
$recipients = array('jdoe@example.com');

if ( isset($_SESSION['manhattan-accounting']) && $_SESSION['manhattan-accounting'] )
    $recipients[] = 'bsmith@example.com';
```

Comment: Session approach is the best one if the visit to both pages (heavy text & contact) happens in the same session else COOKIE with "far" expiring date is better (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 0):

`<?php setcookie('name', 'value'); ?>`. I could have sworn they were able to be set using `$_COOKIE['name'] = 'value';` notation, but clearly that's not the case.

You can then check it with `<?php if(!empty($_COOKIE['name'])) ... ?>`

Read http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php for more info.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. It's also worth noting that the cookie won't be available in `$_COOKIE` in the same request during which you set it; it becomes available in the _next_ request.

Answer (score 0):

in text_heavy.php

```
<?php

setcookie("manhattan-accounting", time());

?>
```

in concat_form.php

```
<?php

$cc=array();

if(isset($_COOKIE['manhattan-accounting'])){
   $cc[]="manhattan@sales.example.com";
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['washington-accounting'])){
   $cc[]="washington@sales.example.com";
}

?>
```

this approach permit to memorize different visits to different "special" pages